# How to check/find if multiple letters are in a string | PHP

Tags: php, string, if-statement

So far, I managed to find if ONE letter is in ANY given string. However, I cannot manage to ask for multiple conditions like 'a' && 'e' && 'i'... In a way that all of those letter need to be in the string so the echo "Vowel found" gets out.

I have tried with stristr, strpos... and so far my best guess was deprecated so I couldn't use it.
My last resource, which didn't work anyway, was to nest if conditions to make it work; also tried with arrays with no positive result.

```php
$string = 'murcielago'; // a word with 5 vowels
if (stristr($string, 'a') == TRUE) {
    echo 'Vowel found';
} else {
    echo "Vowel not found";
}
```

This is my code for ONE string or letter to be found in the original given string.

Comment: So you just want to check if any vowel is in the string? It doesn't matter the order or if there are two or more. You just want to check if a single vowel or more are anywhere in the string?

Comment: Yes. something like:
if letter 'a' && 'b' %% 'c' in $string:
echo "all of those letters are in the string"; So far I saw that one function gives you 1 if it finds the "string"(vowel in this case) on the given word so I would be just looking for a way that all conditions are TRUE to give green light to echo. Now I gotta figure how to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

It made me think further! Got it.

```
$string = "murcielago";

if (strpos($string,'a') && strpos($string,'e') && strpos($string,'i') && strpos($string,'o') && strpos($string,'u') == true) 
{
 echo "nailed it";
} else { 
         echo "No vowels for you"; 
       } 
´´´

I wonder if there is any way to make all the conditions into one since I am still using the same strpos function.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex and [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$string = 'murcielago';

// This will echo "vowel found"
if(preg_match( '`[aeiouy]`', $string)){
   
    echo "vowel found\n";
}

$string2 = 'bcdfgplk';

// This won't echo anything
if(preg_match( '`[aeiouy]`', $string2 )){
    echo "vowel not found\n";
}
```